# How can this integral be evaluated?

Tags: integration

I am trying to find the definite integral of this function. When entered into wolfram alpha the result (shown below) is given. However I do not understand what the E (elliptic integral of the second kind) is, and how it fits into the equation. So what is the E term? Can it be expanded into the rest of the definite integral?
$$ \int \sqrt{1+\dfrac{p^2 x^2}{q^2(q^2-x^2)}}dx  $$

[image: Here is the result from wolfram alpha]

Comment: If you look at the description at the bottom of the image, $E$ is the elliptic integral. If you look at the form for the elliptic integral (check Wikipedia), you'll see that the answer is more or less restating your answer and isn't in much simpler terms.

Comment: This is an example of when an antiderivative cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. For a simpler example, you cannot integrate $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ (or rather, you can, but the result cannot be written in terms of polynomials, logarithms, exponentials, trigonometric functions, etc.). Most functions do not have elementary antiderivatives.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int \sqrt{1+\frac{q^2x^2}{p^2(q^2-x^2)}}dx$$
Let $x=q \sin t$, then
$$I=\frac{1}{p}\int \sqrt{p^2\cos^2 t+q^2 \sin^2 t} dt =\int \sqrt{p^2+(q^2-p^2) \sin^2 t} dt$$
It leads to an elliptic Integral